# How to print "Hello world!" using Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a 51 year old man who recently started to learn Python programming. I struggled to follow most Python programming tutorials because I am stuck on part one which obviously asks readers to print "hello world" on a console. Here's what I tried so far:

```
prin 'Hello world!'
```

and I even tried this:

```
prnt 'Hello world!'
```

I got the following error on Python shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'prnt' is not defined
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I can't find anything in Google that resolves this error. I really need help from you guys, thanks!

Comment: Python 2 is no longer supported, you should be using Python 3.8.

Comment: Please repeat the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  This is something you look up in your tutorial materials -- not a Stack Overflow issue.

Comment: is `prin` and `prnt` a joke?!

Comment: The error is in the use of prin instead of print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try either of these:

```
print "Hello World!"
print('Hello World')
```

Also, maybe try looking up other tutorials on the basics of python if you are having trouble!

Answer (score 3):

In `Python 2.7`, it is `print 'Hello world!!'`

For latest version of Python, that is, Python 3.x, it is `print('Hello world!!')`